# A problem inspired by the Twin Prime conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, twin-primes

I came up with a question several hours ago...but I couldn't find any information about it.

The problem goes like below

$$P^n_k =\{(p_1,...,p_n)|p_1<...<p_n:primes,p_n-p_1\le k\}$$

$$k_n=min\{k|card(P^n_k)=\infty\}$$

Is $k_n=O(n^m)$ for some $m\in \mathbb N$?

If not, how about log or exponential functions?

I do not expect to get the answer. However, I found this problem interesting and wish to discuss with others about it. I also look forward to some knowledge that can help me to attack this problem.

Thanks for helping~

Edit. I noticed that we should prove the existence of $k_n$ first.